# emulate enum semantics in the bash shell

Tags: bash, shell

I was trying to emulate the C enum semantics with arrays but without much sucess, basically i want to be able to iterate through a set of items and also declare a variable just by using an identifier like this:

```
$ bash -version
GNU bash, versión 4.1.10(4)-release (i686-pc-cygwin)
```

bad attempt:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    STATES=(INITIAL DEFAULT_CS_SETUP  CREATED_CS CHECKED_OUT_DIR MKELEMENT_FILE\
CREATED_BRANCH CHECKED_IN_DIR COMPLETE)
    tam=${#STATES[@]}
    dereference()
    {
       tam=${#STATES[@]}
       for ((j=0; j < $tam; j++)); do
          if [[ "$state" == ${STATES[j]} ]];then
           echo $j
           break
         fi
       done
    }

    echo get the INITIAL state
    state=INITIAL
    echo ${STATES[`dereference`]}

    echo get the next state from CREATED_CS
    state=CREATED_CS
    echo ${STATES[`dereference`+1]}

    echo list elements from CREATED_CS to the end
    state=CREATED_CS
    for ((i=`dereference`; i < $tam; i++)); do
      echo ${STATES[$i]}
    done

    echo list elements from CREATED_CS to CREATED_BRANCH is really awkward
    state=CREATED_BRANCH
    tmp_ind=`dereference`
    state=CREATED_CS
    for ((i=`dereference`; i <= $tmp_ind; i++)); do
      echo ${STATES[$i]}
    done
```

output:

```
get the INITIAL state
INITIAL
get the next state from CREATED_CS
CHECKED_OUT_DIR
list elements from CREATED_CS to the end
CREATED_CS
CHECKED_OUT_DIR
MKELEMENT_FILE
CREATED_BRANCH
CHECKED_IN_DIR
COMPLETE
list elements from CREATED_CS to CREATED_BRANCH is really awkward
CREATED_CS
CHECKED_OUT_DIR
MKELEMENT_FILE
CREATED_BRANCH
```

The bottom question is not about the correctness of the above code, instead i have a script with states and transitions, and i dont want to remember each state by and index, i want to use labels instead.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are happy with using a few `$` signs here and there, how about you declare some constants:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

STATES=(INITIAL DEFAULT_CS_SETUP CREATED_CS CHECKED_OUT_DIR MKELEMENT_FILE CREATED_BRANCH CHECKED_IN_DIR COMPLETE)
tam=${#STATES[@]}
for ((i=0; i < $tam; i++)); do
    name=${STATES[i]}
    declare -r ${name}=$i
done

echo get the INITIAL state
echo ${STATES[$INITIAL]}

echo get the next state from CREATED_CS
echo ${STATES[$CREATED_CS+1]}

echo list elements from CREATED_CS to the end
for ((i=$CREATED_CS; i < $tam; i++)); do
    echo ${STATES[$i]}
done

echo list elements from CREATED_CS to CREATED_BRANCH
for ((i=$CREATED_CS; i <= $CREATED_BRANCH; i++)); do
    echo ${STATES[$i]}
done
```

Comment: +1 the only caveat is that by maintaining information twice, i have to remember to also recreate the constants if i ever add or substract an element in the array

Comment: If you leave it to the code like I did, you don't have to worry about that. Just update the array, the constants will be created automatically.